# Identifying the error in using a View constructor missing AttributeSet

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-view

As a beginning Android programmer who is not a beginning programmer, I am alarmed by the amount of time it took me until I realized that the crash was resulting from omitting to use the constructor taking `AttributeSet` as a second parameter and writing instead the following code for a custom view defined in an XML layout.

////////MyView.java////////

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public SimpleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    ...

}
```

My question is this: What could I have done (in Eclipse, the ADT variant) to be able to determine this error quickly? I look rather carefully at lint messages and was hoping that that habit would spare me spending hours for a single error.

The manual does of course clearly state that custom views defined in an XML layout should use the `(Context, AttributeSet)` variant of the View constructor, but it is hopeless to program at any level while recalling with precision every last detail in the reference pages.

Comment: What were the LogCat errors?

Comment: None! The LogCat is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be the following error in the Graphical Layout:

> Custom view MyView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View
>   constructors; XML attributes will not work

But I agree that a compile-time error would be better...

Comment: I see it. That's very interesting. It is not exposed in the project/package explorer. It looks like Eclipse considers it a low-level warning. Presumably this means that it would be a good habit after writing Java files to take a look again at the layout files and make sure no messages appear below the graphical layout.